# For loop variable as column name

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

As an example, I have created a small vector containing the column names of a dataframe, I want to loop these variables in order to delete certain values within the column where the variable `i` equals the column name

Creating the vector:

```
Ellenberg_value<- c( "VOCHTIND", "ZUURGIND", "STIKSIND", "ZOUT_IND")
```

For loop:

```
for (i in Ellenberg_value) {
    Ecobase<- Ecobase[!Ecobase$i== "X",]
    Ecobase<- Ecobase[!Ecobase$i== "?",]
}
```

I expect the output dataframe wihtout the X's and ? within the columns which are specified in the vector. However, now I get an empty dataframe

Comment: Try `Ecobase[!Ecobase[[i]] == "X", ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to subset with another mechanism (using `[[` instead of `$`), when the column names are stored as character vectors. An example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1 ,b = 3)
cols <- names(df)
```

The following works as intended:

```
for (i in cols) {
  print(i)
  print(df[[i]])
}
[1] "a"
[1] 1
[1] "b"
[1] 3
```

Whereas your code doesn't:

```
for (i in cols) {
  print(i)
  print(df$i)
}
[1] "a"
NULL
[1] "b"
NULL
```

In your code you may therefore use `Ecobase[!Ecobase[[i]] == "X", ]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a loop is necessary. If I understand you correctly you want to delete the rows in which at least one of the columns `"VOCHTIND", "ZUURGIND", "STIKSIND", "ZOUT_IND"` equals `"X"`, is that correct?

```
Ecobase[rowSums(Ecobase[,Ellenberg_value] == "X") == 0,]
```

If you want to get rid of rows with an "?" as well, you could do:

```
Ecobase[rowSums(sapply(Ecobase[Ellenberg_value], '%in%', c("X", "?"))) == 0,]
```